# Generating Custom Patient IDs in Access Database using VBA UDF

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

First, let me say this. I am new to using access and VBA functions.

My overall goal is to add functionality to my database as described below:

This database consists of patients enrolled in a Clinical Trial, these patients have a unique identifier in the format GKID-XXXXX where the XXXXX is an alphanumeric base 35 counting system.

Eg. the numbering goes like this GKID-00000, GKID-00001, GKID-00002, GKID-00003,... , GKID-0000Z. Base 35 because it exclude the letter O.

Previously, we would generate these IDs and type them in manually. However, in the future, we would like these to be automatically created when a new patient is added to the database. However,
we want to retain the ability to add IDs in manually without changing any existing IDs, delete records without changing the assigned IDs, and the IDs created cannot be already used.

I have tried many things and the naive strategy I have made progress with is as follows.

1. Take the existing "Working Table" that contains all of the existing IDs in a field. This field would be left blank for newly added patients who we want to automatically generate an ID for.
2. Using this working table, create a new table with a query. This would be the table with the IDs. It would exactly match the existing table except the ID column from the first table would be replaced with one that generates IDs with a custom VBA function. The function takes the Working Table ID field in as a variable and returns the generated ID. If the field is occupied, it simply returns the ID, if not, it generates a new one. Below is the progress I have made in accomplishing this.

```
Option Compare Database
Function GavFun2(EIID As String) As String
strAlphabet = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ"
```

These are the characters in the base 35 counting system.

```
N = Mid(EIID, 6, 5)
```

This simply extracts the 5 alphanumeric digits of the Working Table ID

```
Dec = (InStr(strAlphabet, Mid(N, 5, 1)) - 1) * 35 ^ 0 + (InStr(strAlphabet, Mid(N, 4, 1)) - 1) * 35 ^ 1 + (InStr(strAlphabet, Mid(N, 3, 1)) - 1) * 35 ^ 2 + (InStr(strAlphabet, Mid(N, 2, 1)) - 1) * 35 ^ 3 + (InStr(strAlphabet, Mid(N, 1, 1)) - 1) * 35 ^ 4
```

This Decodes this back into a base 10 system

```
GavFun2 = GavFun(CInt(Dec))
```

This converts the number back into the base 35 system and returns the ID in its full string form (function included below).

```
If EIID = Empty Then
 
 
    
End If

End Function
```

This if statement is where I am running into a wall. I want to fund the maximum value of Cint(Dec), then simply return GavFun2 = GavFun(Max(Cint(Dec))+1). I feel like this would be a good start, but there would be a number of problems if I was able to even get this to work.

A.  If there ware multiple blank records, they would all have the ID (maybe replace with a for loop that runs through each blank consecutively and start the counter at Max(Cint(Dec))+1, but I don’t know how to do this.)

B.  If I were to add a new patient with a custom ID (or delete one), this could potentially change all of the generated IDs.
Any thoughts on my general approach or advice on how to proceed would be very much appreciated. Thank you so much for your help.

```
Option Compare Database
Function GavFun(IDD As Integer) As String
strAlphabet = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ"
If IDD = 0 Then
  GavFun = "0"
    Exit Function
End I
GavFun = vbNullString
Do While IDD <> 0
  GavFun = Mid(strAlphabet, IDD Mod 35 + 1, 1) & GavFun
    IDD = IDD \ 35
Loop
ZZ = Array("0", "00", "000", "0000", "00000")
L = Len(CStr(GavFun))
MM = ZZ(4 - L)
GavFun = "GKID-" & MM & GavFun
End Function
```

Comment: If you use an autonumber field in your patient table then you can convert the autonumber value to your base 35 Patient ID.

Comment: Can you illustrate your problem with sample data including current data and desired results?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the way to approach this?

Well we often need all kinds of speical numbering systems. For invoice, PO numbers, maybe a badge number, employee numbers etc. Now in these cases? Such numbers have VERY little to do with relational databases. I mean becuase you might not yet have some silly invoice number, your whole software package comes crashing down?

So, such external numbers? They don't have anything to do with how you build your relationships between tables. For that you use the PK (ID - autonumber), and then the FK (forighen key) in the child table. things like City, invoice number, name etc? That's just data you store - ZERO to do with relationships.

Ok, so now that we got above out of the way.

First up:
You don't want to hit the whole database to find some max number or some such. While this might work for single user, it not really a good idea.

So, for badge numbers, incrementing product numbers, invoice numbers, and hey, maybe even a clincial trial number?

You create a table with a SINGLE row in that table. That way you can then even say go and change/set what the starting number/point is to be. So yes, you ARE on the right tack - you want to build your own custom numbering system, and then use that for a column in that table (as I stated, this is just a number, or value - not different then city, first name, or say some invoice number - NOTHING to do with the PK, and NOTHING to do with relatonal database stuff.

Ok, so, now we need some things here.

First, we need that table that keeps track of this number for us.

Next, we need a routine to get this "value" and then increment the value for the next time.

And then we need to setup a nice way to get and then put/shove/have that number auto matic be setup and entered into that form for us, and of course make sure if that record already has a number, we don't over write it.

Thus we can break this problem down into separate parts.

First, create our increment number handy dandy maintains table like this:

[image]

So that's our table. Nice part is we can edit the starting number, and even the prefix - so if you do another run/study, we can easy start a new number set. we DON'T care about the existing data - build a number system - it just runs and works like a good water pump.

Ok, next we need our routine to go please get me the next number.

Our code can work like this:

```
  Public Function GetNextPID() As String
  
     Const Alpha = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ"
     Const MaxDigts = 4
     Const Base = 35
     Dim OnePart       As Long
     Dim OneDigit      As Long
     Dim rstNext       As DAO.Recordset
     Dim OurNum        As Long
     Dim i             As Integer
     Dim strResult     As String
     Dim strPrefix     As String
     
     
     Set rstNext = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("NextPatientNum")
     OurNum = rstNext!NextNumber
     strPrefix = rstNext!Prefix
     rstNext.Edit
     rstNext!NextNumber = OurNum + 1
     rstNext.Update
     rstNext.Close
     
     ' convert our number to base
     Dim s As String
     
     For i = MaxDigts - 1 To 0 Step -1
     
        OnePart = Int(OurNum / (Base ^ i))
        s = Mid(Alpha, OnePart + 1, 1)
        
        strResult = strResult & s
        
        OurNum = OurNum - Int(OnePart * (Base ^ i))
     
     Next i
     
     GetNextPID = strPrefix & "-" & strResult
  
  End Function
```

So, place the above code function in a standard code module (not in a form).

Now, hit ctrl-g, and we can test it like this from the debug (immediate window)

```
? GetNextPID
Output: GKID-0007
```

So, now you can just edit that "one row" maintains table to start at whatever number you like or feel like. once you set that number, then each time you call that routine, it will go get you the next number based on our new number system.

Now, all we have to do is in that form? Well, we could just write code to check if the text box/field is not yet set, but there is ALSO a event on the form that fires ONLY when you add/insert that record in the form. It not 100% clear when/how your form works, but we can do something like this:

```
  Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(Cancel As Integer)
  
      Me.PatientNum = GetNextPID
  
  End Sub
```

(of course you don't type in the event stub part).

Note close: if the record is blank - not dirty, then nothing happens. You can even close the form. However, the instant you start typing anything into that form with a new record, then like magic that code will run, and shove in the new number into that text box on the form, the new patient number will appear.

As noted, we can even go edit that maintains table, give it a new prefix and new number for a whole new study.

Edit: feel free to use your existing logic - either way, don't try and hit/use the database table with existing data to get/make/generate the new ID - use your function idea, but it will simple automatic return + generate the next new number you need upon calling that function.